# Getting hazed figure when exporting a high resolution image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, imagery, resolution

I have a raster map made in QGIS. I am trying to export that map in .tiff format in high resolution (Somewhere around I can get a file of 300 MB).

[image]

So I am exporting the image with a resolution of 960 dpi (using the option `Export Map to Image..`.

But all I am getting is a hazed figure like this:

[image]

What could be the possible solution for this issue?

At 600 dpi, I am getting an image like this on exporting:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you export the image at 600 dpi? I guess 960 dpi is very huge and 600 dpi as well, so maybe your computer couldn't handle it.

Comment: Let me export it for 600 dpi and see.. Is it the problem of processor of my computer?

Comment: I am not sure, It can be a memroy issue.

Comment: @ahmadhanb At 600dpi, it is coming out to be less hazed.

Comment: How big the size of the output image, because I think it is a memory issue? To confirm this, do you have access to another computer with better specifications, especially RAM?

Comment: @ahmadhanb For 960 dpi it's about 300 mb and for 600 dpi its around 120 mb. The computer which I am using has 8 GB RAM. It could take some time to arrange for a computer with better specifications.